# I am a creature known from ancient legends

Tags: riddle, word

My head has horns.
My neck is a dwelling.
My shoulders bear heavy loads.
My whole is a song.

What am I?

**Hint #1:**

> My name consists of two of my parts.

**Hint #2:**

> I come from the Middle East, but the Romans spread me throughout the world.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you

> the [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_alphabet)?

My head has horns.

> A derives from the Phoenician ʾālep, meaning an ox.

My neck is a dwelling.

> B derives from the Phoenician bēt, meaning a house.

My shoulders bear heavy loads.

> C derives from the Phoenician gīml, meaning a camel.

My whole is a song.

> Everyone knows the alphabet song, right? A, B, C, D, E, F, G...

Hint #1:

> My name consists of two of my parts, **alpha (A) and bet (B)**.

Hint #2:

> I come from the Middle East (**the Phoenician alphabet**), but the Romans spread me throughout the world (**the Roman alphabet**).

Comment: We have a winner!

Comment: Wow. Very creative riddle and solution.

Comment: One of the best riddles I've ever come across. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> a building.

My head has horns.

> Antennas for 'horns' in the head.

My neck is a dwelling.

> Apartments for dwellings on the neck.

My shoulders bear heavy loads.

> The vertical beams bear heavy loads.

My whole is a song.

> Your whole is [The Building Song](http://hymns.wikia.com/wiki/The_building_song).

Comment: Good effort, but not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly:

> A lighthouse

My head has horns:

> The top of a lighthouse can appear as a horn.

My neck is a dwelling:

> People can enter into the neck of the lighthouse.

My shoulders bear heavy loads.

> This is a metaphor. Lighthouses are given the responsibility of keeping ships safe, which is metaphorically a heavy load for their shoulders.

My whole is a song.

> [A song about a lighthouse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARIr6S_0lAQ)

Hint:

> A lighthouse has a light, and it has a house. Therefore the two parts of its name are two of its parts.

Title:

> Lighthouses have certainly existed since ancient times, such as the Lighthouse of Alexandria.

Comment: I really like this answer!  But, it's not the one I had in mind when I wrote the riddle.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably a

> [Satyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyr)

As we can see

First one: **My head has horns**

> [image: Phil frm Hercules(Disney)]

Second one: **My neck is a dwelling.**

> It refers to the [Nymphs](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Nymphs) as Satyrs are attracted towards them.

The third line is what's confusing...

Last one **My whole is a song.**

> A play on words, a similar word is : Satire.

Comment: What about the hint ?

Comment: The time I started writing this answer, the hint was not there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my second attempt:

> Bagpipes

My head has horns:

> The pipes sticking out of the top appear like horns.

My neck is a dwelling:

> The neck could be the bag, which fills with air.

My shoulders bear heavy loads:

> I can't think of anything too good for this one, Possibly, the player pressing against the bag with his arm is the heavy load.

My whole is a song:

> Bagpipes create music.

Hint 1:

> The bag and the pipes are part of the instrument.

Hint 2:

> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagpipes#Ancient_origins), the earliest archeological references to bagpipes come from the Hittites, in the Middle East. According to the same article, bagpipes were common in Rome, and the empire spread them to several places.